# How to change the formatting of the URL fields when exporting from pandas to excel using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I try to change the formatting of the URL fields which I got from saving pandas to excel

Code below should work for all usable area of my excel file but for some reason first column which contain web adresses didn't changed its style. Instead it still use the default excel formatting

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"{date_filename}.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")

df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='current')

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['current']

font_format = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Calibri', 'font_size': 13})
header_format = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Calibri', 'font_size': 13, 'bold': True})

worksheet.set_column('A:H', None, font_format)
worksheet.set_row(0, None, header_format)


writer.save()
```

My df have a few columns where the first one is a url one (an object Dtype)

```
#   Column                Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                --------------  -----  
 0   url                   2 non-null      object
```

Where I store w.g.

```
https://google.com in a first row, 
https://amazon.com in a second etc
```

I am wondering why it keeps the default excel formatting.

Answer (score 1):

i really don't see the problem, but to be sure, it is recommended that you don't declare the variable `writer = pd.ExcelWriter` instead use `whit`

example code

```
import pandas as pd

tops = [
    {"name": "google", "url": "https://www.google.com"},
    {"name": "amazon", "url": "https://www.amazon.com"},
    {"name": "apple", "url": "https://www.apple.com"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(tops)

with pd.ExcelWriter("excel.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name="current")

    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets["current"]

    font_format = workbook.add_format({"font_name": "Calibri", "font_size": 13})
    header_format = workbook.add_format(
        {"font_name": "Calibri", "font_size": 13, "bold": True}
    )

    worksheet.set_column("A:H", None, font_format)
    worksheet.set_row(0, None, header_format)

print("save")
```

**response**

[image]

this it worked!

Comment: still the same issue at my side. Look at this screenshot - https://share.cleanshot.com/SoYsGW

I dont know why excel uses the default values for url, when formatted for other fields.

Comment: Could you add an example of the data you want to work on?

Comment: Christian Gtz your example dataframe is perfectly fine. Do you have properly formatted url column at your side using this example? 13 px? Because it can be a problem with excel.

Comment: I have the format de 13 px, only copy your code and modify the statement "with"